# How to create embedded array of documents and further create embedded document on each element

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I have three mongoDB collections and their respective documents namely; mosques, prayers and subscriptions as follows:

#### mosque document:

```
{
  "_id": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
  "address": "pti road , effurun",
  "city": "Warri",
  "state": "Delta",
  "country": "Nigeria",
  "name": "PTI central mosque",
  "image": "",
  "imamName": "Malam malam",
  "verified": false,
  "active": true,
  "__v": 0
}
```

#### prayer document:

```
{
  "_id":"64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb".
  "title": "Subhi",
  "adhaanTime": "05:10",
  "iqaamaTime": "05:20",
  "imamName": "Malam Suleiman",
  "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
  "__v": 0
}
```

#### subscription document

```
{
  "_id":"64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
  "user":"649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
  "service":"64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6"
  "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to be able to query a single mosque with its associated prayers and each prayer with its subscriptions using aggregation like so:

```
{
  "_id": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
  "address": "pti road , effurun",
  "city": "Warri",
  "state": "Delta",
  "country": "Nigeria",
  "name": "PTI central mosque",
  "image": "",
  "imamName": "Malam malam",
  "verified": false,
  "active": true,
  "prayers": [
    {
      "_id":"64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb".
      "title": "Subhi",
      "adhaanTime": "05:10",
      "iqaamaTime": "05:20",
      "imamName": "Malam Suleiman",
      "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
      "__v": 0,
      "subscriptions": [
          {
            "_id":"64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
            "user":"649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
            "service":"64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6"
            "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id":"6546775e5fd0db3668806e45446",
            "user":"649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
            "service":"64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6"
            "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "__v": 0
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id":"64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb".
      "title": "Subhi",
      "adhaanTime": "05:10",
      "iqaamaTime": "05:20",
      "imamName": "Malam Suleiman",
      "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
      "__v": 0,
      "subscriptions": [
          {
            "_id":"64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
            "user":"649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
            "service":"64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6"
            "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id":"6546775e5fd0db3668806e45446",
            "user":"649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
            "service":"64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6"
            "mosque":"64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "__v": 0
          }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

How do I achieve that?

This is the aggregate I attempted to build:

```
const result = await Mosque.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(mosqueId),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "prayers",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "mosque",
        as: "prayers",
      },
    },
 
    {
      $set: {
        "prayers.subscriptions": "subscriptions",
      },
    },
  ]);
```

And I got the following result:

```
{
    "mosque": [
        {
            "_id": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "user": {
                "_id": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                "firstName": "Bello",
                "otherName": "sani",
                "phoneNumber": "+6575455475",
                "email": "",
                "authProvider": "credentials",
                "password": "$2a$10$Ednofrd3dxjWzgDC77rq1umrNhpzAKc.ypzksQ3rbOWTd7lKSFGC6",
                "location": "my town",
                "lga": "my town",
                "state": "my town",
                "country": "my town",
                "verified": false,
                "active": true,
                "role": "user",
                "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:21:25.067Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:21:25.067Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "address": "pti road , effurun",
            "city": "Warri",
            "state": "Delta",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "name": "PTI central mosque",
            "image": "",
            "imamName": "Malam Malam",
            "verified": false,
            "active": true,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-04T21:19:29.365Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-04T21:19:29.365Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "prayers": [
                {
                    "_id": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                    "title": "Subhi",
                    "adhaanTime": "05:10",
                    "iqaamaTime": "05:20",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:16:18.641Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-05T23:16:18.641Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": "subscriptions"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a5fca4f11d298e8081b847",
                    "title": "Zuhr",
                    "adhaanTime": "01:42",
                    "iqaamaTime": "00:50",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:28:36.180Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-06T23:54:38.111Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": "subscriptions"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a5fecaf11d298e8081dd6e",
                    "title": "Asr",
                    "adhaanTime": "04:05",
                    "iqaamaTime": "04:15",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:37:46.418Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-06T23:55:21.588Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": "subscriptions"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                    "title": "Magrib",
                    "adhaanTime": "06:55",
                    "iqaamaTime": "07:05",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-07T00:25:18.282Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-07T10:37:26.153Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": "subscriptions"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to replace "subscriptions" with matching list of subscription documents from the subscriptions collection

Comment: What have you tried? What is the association between a subscription and a prayer? Seems like you can probably achieve what you want via `$lookup`

Comment: @user20042973  I have updated the questions with what I have implemented and what I got

Comment: Looks like you're pretty close. Need to do another `$lookup` to pull the subscriptions. You could either do that as a separate top level stage and then reshape the document in the `$set` as you're currently doing, or use the `pipeline` functionality of `$lookup` to embed the other one in the first (potentially preventing the need to do that final `$set` at all).

Comment: @user20042973 thanks so much. Following your suggestion, I was able to complete the aggregation to get exactly what I want.

Comment: @user20042973  If you look at the result at the moment, the same array of subscriptions are embedded to all prayers. I would like to filter the subscriptions to include only the ones whose service matches the prayer Id.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete aggregation that I was looking for:

```
const result = await Mosque.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "prayers",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "mosque",
        as: "prayers",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "subscriptions",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("649966a5cba88e510479da00"),
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "subs",
      },
    },

    {
      $set: {
        "prayers.subscriptions": "$subs",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        subs: 0,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

The result of the aggregation:

```
{
    "mosque": [
        {
            "_id": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
            "user": {
                "_id": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                "firstName": "",
                "otherName": "",
                "phoneNumber": "5865474447",
                "email": "",
                "authProvider": "credentials",
                "password": "$2a$10$Ednofrd3dxjWzgDC77rq1umrNhpzAKc.ypzksQ3rbOWTd7lKSFGC6",
                "location": "my town",
                "lga": "my town",
                "state": "my town",
                "country": "my town",
                "verified": false,
                "active": true,
                "role": "user",
                "createdAt": "2023-06-26T10:21:25.067Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-06-26T10:21:25.067Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "address": "pti road , effurun",
            "city": "Warri",
            "state": "Delta",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "name": "PTI central mosque",
            "image": "",
            "imamName": "Malam malam",
            "verified": false,
            "active": true,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-04T21:19:29.365Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-04T21:19:29.365Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "prayers": [
                {
                    "_id": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                    "title": "Subhi",
                    "adhaanTime": "05:10",
                    "iqaamaTime": "05:20",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:16:18.641Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-05T23:16:18.641Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": [
                        {
                            "_id": "64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "64aae139fd0db3668806e55d",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a5fca4f11d298e8081b847",
                    "title": "Zuhr",
                    "adhaanTime": "01:42",
                    "iqaamaTime": "00:50",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:28:36.180Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-06T23:54:38.111Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": [
                        {
                            "_id": "64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "64aae139fd0db3668806e55d",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a5fecaf11d298e8081dd6e",
                    "title": "Asr",
                    "adhaanTime": "04:05",
                    "iqaamaTime": "04:15",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-05T23:37:46.418Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-06T23:55:21.588Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": [
                        {
                            "_id": "64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "64aae139fd0db3668806e55d",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                    "title": "Magrib",
                    "adhaanTime": "06:55",
                    "iqaamaTime": "07:05",
                    "imamName": "Malam malam",
                    "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                    "createdAt": "2023-07-07T00:25:18.282Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-07-07T10:37:26.153Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "subscriptions": [
                        {
                            "_id": "64aac5e5fd0db3668806e4ee",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a75b6e4c57834c539faea6",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T14:36:21.834Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "64aae139fd0db3668806e55d",
                            "user": "649966a5cba88e510479da0a",
                            "service": "64a5f9c2f11d298e808170cb",
                            "mosque": "64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9",
                            "createdAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-07-09T16:32:57.694Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Explanation of the pipelines:

1. **First $match pipeline**:
   This filters the "mosques" collection to grab a mosque with matching ID.
2. **The first $lookup pipeline:**
   This pipeline grabs documents from "prayers" collection and join them with
   the mosque from the previous "$match" pipeline.
3. **Second $lookup pipeline:**
   Here, subscription documents with matching user ID from the subscriptions collection are grabbed, and the result is named "subs". This ensures that only the currently logged in user's subscriptions are fetched.
4. **The $set pipeline:**
   This pipeline create new field "subscriptions" on each "prayer" document and assigns result (i.e. "subs") from the previous $lookup pipeline to it.
5. **The $project pipeline:**
   $ project pipeline helps to remove the unwanted field "subs" that the last $lookup added to the mosque.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were able to [successfully create a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649939/20042973) that achieved most of your results. The pending requirement [expressed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648411/how-to-create-embedded-array-of-documents-and-further-create-embedded-document-o?noredirect=1#comment135143240_76648411) seems to be the following:

> If you look at the result at the moment, the same array of subscriptions are embedded to all prayers. I would like to filter the subscriptions to include only the ones whose service matches the prayer Id

That goes back to [one of my initial questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648411/how-to-create-embedded-array-of-documents-and-further-create-embedded-document-o?noredirect=1#comment135136641_76648411) which was:

> What is the association between a subscription and a prayer?

Per your comment the relationship seems to be the `service` field in subscription documents refers back to the `_id` of the prayer documents. Taking that into account and simplifying a bit, one solution to this may be nesting the `$lookup`s as follows:

```
db.mosques.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("64a48ce14ebcac9ec9a3b0b9"),
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "prayers",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "mosque",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "subscriptions",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "service",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  user: ObjectId("649966a5cba88e510479da00"),
                },
              },
            ],
            as: "subs",
          },
        }
      ],
      as: "prayers",
    },
  },
])
```

Demonstration in [this playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/STieW8HGXP2).

One minor note here is that I've removed the `user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("649966a5cba88e510479da00")` filter that you had in your version. I did this under the assumption that it is already naturally expressed by the more direct relationship of the `service` field. If my assumption is incorrect and this `user` check is separately needed, then you can add that `pipeline` argument back to the embedded `$lookup`.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been trying to achieve. Thank you so much